# Adding Nested Objects Arrays to Firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an array called Pages. My application allows users to add page objects to the page array. The data is then sent to Firestore. I've tried using a For Loop to iterate through each object in the array and send it to Firestore but it doesn't seem to be working. What am I doing wrong?

(I'm using Mobx instead of state to store info which is why I don't have this.state mentioned anywhere)

```
     let id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
     let docTitle = this.projectTitle.title;

     for(let i = 0; i > this.pages.length; i++){

     let pageT = this.pages[i].pageTitle;
     let pageD = this.pages[i].pageDesc;

     db.collection(docTitle + id).doc(pageT).set({
         page: {pageTitle:pageT, pageDesc: pageD, blocks:['item', 'item'], id:'' }
       })
       .then(function() {
         console.log("Document successfully written!");
       })
       .catch(function(error) {
         console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
       });

     }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Use forEach (no need in i etc)
2. Key duplicated in bot doc I'd and inside object. Dont use title as key.
3. Flatten object that you gonna save.

Comment: That worked, thanks. How would I go about adding the 'blocks' array that each object has? It's causing errors.

Comment: Try to use array methods from firestore docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array and recent update about arrays in their blog https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/better-arrays-in-cloud-firestore.html

Comment: That seems to allow me to add individual items to an array but doesn't allow me to add the whole array. I think I need to find some way of separating the array into individual variables and then adding them. I'm getting an error: FirebaseError: Function FieldValue.arrayUnion() called with invalid data. Nested arrays are not supported

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer using `forEach` is inefficient creating a request for every array value, using `n` (array length) more write operations. (Not to mention the time it will take if using `await` on each write).

I'm using NodeJS/Javascript so this should work in React as well, but may need to be slightly modified, the key point is the `...` (`getSearchSubstrings` returns an array):

```
db.collection(x).doc(y).update({
   accountSearch: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(...getSearchSubstrings(username))
})
```

According to their [Update elements in a array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array) documentation, there are two ways of doing it:

```
// To add or remove multiple items, pass multiple arguments to arrayUnion/arrayRemove
const multipleUnionRes = await washingtonRef.update({
  regions: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion('south_carolina', 'texas')
  // Alternatively, you can use spread operator in ES6 syntax
  // const newRegions = ['south_carolina', 'texas']
  // regions: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(...newRegions)
});
```